# Algorithms/methods to minimize the response from a model?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize, nonlinear-optimization

I am working with a dataset where I want to minimize levels of a variable, which we can call V1. I have other variables in this dataset, which we can call V2-V10. Variables V2-V5 have been determined to be controllable, meaning that we can manually change levels of these variables. Each variable is continuous (float).

My goal is to tweak levels of V2-V5, such that I minimize the levels of V1.

My thought process is to construct a model that treats V1 as the response, and V2-V10 as explanatories. I've fit an XGBRegressor() model.

From there, I am thinking to introduce some kind of optimization algorithm that tweaks levels of the controllable variables (V2-V5) such that we are minimizing levels of the response (V1).

Assuming that the model has been fit, what methods or algorithms exist for solving this further? Is this thought process correct, or is there a better way to solve? Python methods are preferred.

Comment: Show us the model and it might be possible to make some informed comments. Your question as posed is far too vague to give anything like a sensible answer. A minimal example would go a long way to providing something we could work with. If you have no idea what you are dealing with simplex algorithms sometimes work OK.

Comment: I've edited my post to be more descriptive. All tags are continuous. I've fit an XGBRegressor model treating X1 as the response and X2-X10 as explantories.

Comment: XGBRegressor isn't continuous, so you'd probably run into the issue that any optimizer that requires gradients, such as scipy.optimize.minimize wouldn't work. Probably you could use scipy.optimize.differential_evolution. Do you have a way to get additional observations? The optimizer may choose an area that you have very little data in.

Comment: I'll take a look into differential_evolution. I am currently using dual_annealing() from scipy.optimize and have defined bounds on my controllable tags. My objective function is designed to minimize the response. Admittedly I am fairly naive on any type of optimization algorithms.